# Check the timestamp value is in current month or not in PHP

Tags: php, date

I just want to know, how to check the timestamp(any month, any year, any date) is present in the current month or not in PHP?

For.eg **1456132659** This is an example timestamp which indicates the last month date. I want a condition like

```
if(1456132659 is in current month) {
//true 
}
else {
//false
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Current month as in 'March 2016' or as in 'March, any year'?

Answer (score 3):

Simply compare the `month` -

```
if(date('m', 1456132659) === date('m')) {
    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to fetch the timestamp of first and last date of current month by using below PHP code-

```
$first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1);
$last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 0, date("n"), date("t"));

// Now just compare the timestamp for above two values by using below condition

if($timestamp >= $first_minute AND $timestamp <= $last_minute) {

    // Your line of code if condtion fullfill.

}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.